# How do I look up the IP address range used by my AWS load balancer for creating instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2

My API accesses a service that wants to know what the possible IP address range is for the API so they can whitelist us. How do I know what IP addresses AWS may assign when the load balancer creates new instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct answer: AWS publishes its IP address ranges in a [publicly accessible JSON file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html). IP ranges are associated with a region and a service, and as you can imagine, there are a lot of them. At the current moment there are 71 CIDR blocks associated with EC2 in us-west-2, for example. That's as specific as you can get, though. So you'd have to supply your partner with all of the EC2 IP address ranges for your region in order to guarantee that they would permit any IP address assigned to an instance your autoscale group might start up. Oh, and they do change periodically, so your partner would have to maintain that list.

Suggestion: Sounds like you have your EC2 instances in public subnets and are assigning public IPs to them. Instead, you can create your EC2 instances in private subnets and use a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) to allow them to access the Internet. If you do this, the source IP for outbound traffic will the be the elastic IP address you assign to the NAT gateway. So you can give your partner a definite IP address they can permit to access their service.

Using a private subnet for your EC2 instances also reduces your attack surface area, since the EC2 instances won't have individual public IP addresses.

Comment: What a great and comprehensive answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ran in to a similar issue so I created this online tool that will let you quickly look up IP address ranges by region and service. Have a look here: https://shotstack.io/tools/aws-ip-search-tool/